# Can derived classes see private members of other derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is it possible to have two different classes derived from the same base class to have access to each other's private data members?

I have a character class with two derived classes, warrior and medic, who have an inventory. Is it possible to implement a checkInventory function that allows the medic to see the inventory of the warrior? Does this function need to be implemented in the base class or separately in each derived class?

Comment: You could use the `friend` keyword. But you have to ask yourself what's special about the relationship between the medic and warrior classes. If it isn't special, you likely have a design problem.

Comment: To put it in crass words: C++ doesn't allow classes the option of touching their siblings' privates

Comment: The rules of your game and the visibility of C++ code portions representing aspects of the game don't have to match so closely. A medic and a warrior may only allow each other to look into their respective inventories, but that tells you nothing about where `public` and `private` are appropriate. Forget about the notion that OOP "models the real world". It's complete and utter nonsense. Chances are that inheritance is even the wrong tool to design those game mechanics in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

"Can derived classes see private members of other derived classes?" - No. Private members are *private*. Derived classes can see `protected` and `public` members of base classes, but not `private`. `friend` classes, however, can see your private members (but needing to use `friend` is *often* a sign of a bad design).
Sibling classes can only see each others `public` parts (in addition to what they can see from their shared base(s)).